# mod_rewrite rules and content negotiation

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, content-negotiation

I am relatively new to mod_rewrite, but have a site which I would like to have "pretty urls." Similarly to SO :).

I am attempting to have things like: "http://www.whatever.com/search/test" get rewritten to "http://www.whatever.com/search.php?q=test" and have had some limited success. I believe that content negotiation is getting in my way...

For starters here's my test .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~user/mysite/

RewriteRule ^search$ search/ [R]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/?$ search.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Which unfortunately, *does* redirect to search.php, but does not pass my param in the q variable. However this *does* work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~user/mysite/

RewriteRule ^search$ search/ [R]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/?$ s.php?q=$1 [L] # here i've renamed the search.php to s.php to dodge the content negotiation that is happening..
```

In fact, if I remove the rules all together, I get the same result as with the first version of the file. So my conclusion is that since apache is happily redirecting "foo" to "foo.php" even without any mod_rewrite rules, that it must be the content negotiation that is taking care of it. (This is further verified by the fact if I renamed my foo.php to foo.html, it still will find the file if i just go to "foo").

So, the question is. How do I properly use mod_rewrite with regard to content negotiation? Can I disable it for a particular file? Is there a way to ensure that my mod_rewrite rules happen before the content negotiation happens?

If it is relevant, here is the conf file for the mod_userdir part of my apache conf (this test site is in my user's homedir/public_html):

```
# Settings for user home directories

<IfDefine USERDIR>
<IfModule userdir_module>

# UserDir: The name of the directory that is appended onto a user's home
# directory if a ~user request is received.  Note that you must also set
# the default access control for these directories, as in the example below.
UserDir public_html

# Control access to UserDir directories.  The following is an example
# for a site where these directories are restricted to read-only.
<Directory /home/*/public_html>
    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
    <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Limit>
    <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>

# Suexec isn't really required to run cgi-scripts, but it's a really good
# idea if you have multiple users serving websites...
<IfDefine SUEXEC>
<IfModule suexec_module>
<Directory /home/*/public_html/cgi-bin>
    Options ExecCGI
    SetHandler cgi-script
</Directory>
</IfModule>
</IfDefine>

</IfModule>
</IfDefine>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for this option in your configuration.

```
Options +Multiviews
```

It will look for

```
/foo/test
/foo/
/foo
```

and redirect them to

```
/foo.[any file]
```

based upon if it exists and if it fits the content-type requested.

Change the option to this to disable this.

```
Options -Multiviews
```