# Unwanted default rewrite/alias

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

On my machine userpage redirects to/is an alias for userpage.html or userpage.php, even before I have not set up any rewrite rules, or even if I turn rewriting off. It must be some default setting that I am unaware of.

I am using apache on Fedora and have not messed with the default configuration, except to turn on name based virtual hosting

I am getting some additional strange results, perhaps related. This code does not work:

```
RewriteRule userpage/vidnum/(.*)$   userpage.php?vidnum=$1 [NC,L]
```

This one does work:

```
RewriteRule vidnum/(.*)$   userpage.php?vidnum=$1 [NC,L]
```

All rewrite rules that I write must live in .htaccess, BTW, due to wanted server hosting flexibility.

My virtual host is set up like this = nothing strange AFAIK:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@keryx.se
    DocumentRoot /home/gunther/arkiv/workspace/webbteknik
    ServerName wt.book
    ErrorLog logs/wt.book-error_log
    CustomLog logs/wt.book-access_log combined
    <Directory /home/gunther/arkiv/workspace/webbteknik>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does the "default redirect" happen even if you set RewriteEngine Off in your .htaccess in in root folder (ie. turning off mod_rewrite)?
Might there be a folder called userpage with an additional .htaccess file in it making the redirect?

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the contents of your .htaccess from the root folder of your application?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out whats happening, thanks to a Twitter friend (@bjori).

It was the content-negotiation that caused all of the above.

Adding:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

In my .htaccess fixes the problem. This makes this question a dupe of [mod-rewrite question: /test/method is rewritten to test.svg/method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360481/mod-rewrite-question-test-method-is-rewritten-to-test-svg-method)

Comment: Another dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444592/mod-rewrite-rules-and-content-negotiation

Comment: And once I've figured this out, I'm finding lots of explanations. Here is a good one: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/rewrite/1/